# Nearly Bessel's Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

In my research I have come across a linear, second-order ordinary differential equation that looks much like Bessel's equation except for one small difference:
\begin{equation}
z^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}R_m(z) + z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}R_m(z) + \left(z^2+Wz-m^2\right)R_m(z) = 0,
\end{equation}
where $m$ and $W$ are constants.  If $W\rightarrow0$, then Bessel's equation is recovered.  I believe this equation may be solved as a series, but its similarity to Bessel's equation makes me wonder if there is another way (maybe through some clever substitution) that makes use of well known functions.  I don't especially want to re-invent the wheel and I have tried to look up this equation, but I have not been able to find anything.  Does anyone know if this equation has previously established solutions?

Comment: Here's Mathematica's anwer (no derivation): Let $f(z)\to g(z) z^m$ then $g(z)= c_1 e^{-i z} U(\frac{1}{2} (2 m+i w+1),2 m+1,2 i z)+c_2 e^{-i z} L(\frac{1}{2} (-2 m-i w-1),2 m,2 i z)$ where $U$ is the confluent hypergeometric function, $L$ is the generalized Laguerre polynomial and $c_1, c_2$ are some (complex) constants.

Comment: I am not very familiar with hypergeometric functions.  Are they easier to work with than working with the series solution directly?

Comment: @MichaelM, depends on the software you have. If you have Mathematica for example, then it's much easier to work with hypergeometric functions because it computes them much faster than the series

Comment: Are there any conditions on your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method to recognize the equation is to make the first order differential term vanish by changing $R_m(z)=z^{-1/2}f(z)$. We obtain
\begin{equation}
z^2f''(z)+ \left(z^2+Wz-m^2+\frac{1}{4}\right)f(z) = 0
\end{equation} 
which is very similar to the [Whittaker's equation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.14.E1). To identify both we further change $z=\tfrac{u}{2i}$ and $f(z)=g(u)$:
\begin{equation}
g''(u)+\left(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{W}{2i}\frac{1}{u}+\frac{\tfrac{1}{4}-m^2}{u^2}\right)g(u) = 0
\end{equation} 
The solutions of the original equation are thus given by
\begin{equation}
R_m(z)=z^{-1/2}\left[AW_{W/2i,m}(2iz)+BM_{W/2i,m}(2iz)  \right]
\end{equation} 
where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants and $W_{\kappa,\mu}$ and $M_{\kappa,\mu}$ are Whittaker functions which are confluent hypergeometric functions. Many of their properties are given in [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13#PT3). This solution is consistent with the Mathematica expression given in comments by @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze

Comment: Thank you!  This really helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea I had. Let's assume $W \ll z$ (which should certainly hold for large enough $z$), then we can use perturbation methods for the equation:

$$z^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}f + z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f + \left(z^2-m^2\right)f+Wzf = 0$$

Assume:

$$f=f_0+W f_1+W^2f_2+\dots$$

Then, by keeping only a certain order of $W$ terms, we have a sequence of equations:

$$z^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}f_0 + z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f_0 + \left(z^2-m^2\right)f_0 = 0$$

This one gives Bessel functions.

$$z^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}f_1 + z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f_1 + \left(z^2-m^2\right)f_1+z f_0 = 0$$

This is inhomogeneous Bessel equation, which also can be solved exactly.

$$z^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}f_2 + z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f_2 + \left(z^2-m^2\right)f_2+z f_1 = 0$$

And so on. In case the Mathematica solution which  Dr. Wolfgang Hintze provided in the comments is not convenient to use, it's always possible to use this perturbation method for large $z$ and the (Frobenius) series method for small $z$.

Comment: A couple of thoughts.  First off, I like that this method provides an asymptotic limit in terms of functions that I am familiar with.  Second, if we are assuming that $Wz\ll z^2$, shouldn't we also assume that $z^2\gg m^2$?  I don't know if this would make much of a difference, but it would switch to a $J_0$ function instead of $J_m$.

Comment: @MichaelM, well, $m$ could be as large as you want, so no, not really. It depends on the particular problem you have. If you are only interested in small $m$, then yes, I suppose. In any case, what I wrote is not exactly rigorous, I don't remember perturbation theory very well, but it's certainly possible to do a more rigorous formulation

Comment: @MichaelM, aslo note that if we get rid of the term with $m^2$ we will never recover it. As for the terms with $W^n$, we always get them back as we move to the next order of perturbation. So potentially, we could go as far as we want and if the functions $f_n$ turn out to have some kind of pattern we could sum the perturbation series and get the exact solution. It was known to happen for some equations